# Structuring a product catalogue in Wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories

I am trying to create a product based content managed website in Wordpress (by clients request). I have created a custom post type where all the products reside, aptly named 'Products'. The products must be shown in different categories as illustrated by the attached image. Being new to Wordpress I am struggling with how to put this together and would like some advice.

Is it best to create a bunch of categories with corresponding pages. When the link is clicked I then somehow filter all the posts in that category? Just a little advice on how the best way to achieve this if possible. Many thanks in advance.

[image: Wordpress menu showing catalogue structure]

Comment: Your question is far too open ended. Concepts can better be discussed in the [WP G+ Developers community](https://plus.google.com/communities/110928980572284315377). If you want to bring it on topic and not get closed, please add what you tried, where you struggled and where we can actually help.

Comment: I was wanting some advice on how best to approach this in Wordpress, both answers I received seemed to be in agreement and not what I would have tried myself so they have help, a lot. I can now go and investigate further. I will also try the link you have suggested. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot looks like a menu, here is how I would do it:

## Custom Taxonomy

Add a new taxonomy for your products e.g. 'Product Type' 'Product Section' or 'Product Category'. It's tempting to assign post categories to that post type but it comes with other issues if you do that, so don't.

You'll want to use [`register_taxonomy`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy), and to list the terms, you'll want to look at functions such as `get_terms` to retrieve the top level terms that dont have parents, then repeat for the next level down

Answer (score 1):

I think its best to register custom taxonomy types otherwise you can [add categories to your CPT code which registers your CPT](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/132090/9884).

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpsites_register_taxonomy_types' );
function wpsites_register_taxonomy_types() {

register_taxonomy( 'cpt-type', 'cpt',
array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name'          => _x( 'Types', 'taxonomy general name', 'theme' ),
        'add_new_item'  => __( 'Add New CPT Type', 'theme' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New CPT Type', 'theme' ),
    ),
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'hierarchical'        => true,
    'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'cpt-type', 'with_front' => false ),
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_tagcloud'       => false,
));

}
```