# Custom post type with new taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a CPT called "products" so in the menu on the left there is "products" and "add new", I want to have "product categories" within the menu too so that the user can add as many product categories as they like, and then when they "add new product" they can assign it to a product category.

Here is how I have registered my CPT:

```
    register_post_type( 'products',
// CPT Options
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Products' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'product' )
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array( 'Product-categories' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products'),
    )
);
```

How do I get a "product categories" taxonomy menu within "products" on the left please?

Thanks

Comment: This has been answered dozens of times already.

Comment: I couldnt find the answer when I searched

Comment: Here's the code http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56087/custom-post-type-archive-template/132090#132090

Comment: Give the linked post an up vote if it helps. Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
  $labels = array(
'name' => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
'singular_name' => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Types','SkyDance' ),
'all_items' => __( 'All Category','SkyDance' ),
'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Category','SkyDance' ),
'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:','SkyDance' ),
'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Categories','SkyDance' ),
'update_item' => __( 'Update Category','SkyDance' ),
'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category,'SkyDance' ),
'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Name','SkyDance' ),

);


    register_taxonomy('category-cpt',array('cpt'), array(
'hierarchical' => true,
'labels' => $labels,
'show_ui' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'category-cpt' ),
 ));
```

Comment: Please provide a proper explanation to your code. Dumping of code is not well received here and also very useless to inexperienced users finding your post from a search engine. Please file an [edit]. Thank you